# Xamarin Studio (Mac / OS X): Solution file (iOS) can no longer be loaded / opened

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I recently tried to open the solution file (.sln) of my iOS-App and noticed it no longer works with Xamarin Studio.

**The error message: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.**

I've been using MSVC 2010 for app developement recently, so I guess this is another example of incompatibilities between Xamarin Studio and MSVC (I'm already used to messed-up "ItemGroups" in the .csproj files, but this seems to be something different).

The version of Xamarin Studio is 5.9.8 (build 0).

Maybe I should also file a bug at Xamarin.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you create a new solution and import the files?

Comment: The solution+project is quite complex with conditional resource stuff etc. I could track down the error by comparing all files with an older version that still worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the .userprefs file solved the problem.

Details:
The root element contained a strange value for "DisabledProjects":

```
<Properties DisabledProjects="&#xA;  ">
```

Xamarin Studio failed to load that expression. Don't know where that came from though.